# Strange function declaration

Tags: c, function

I am was reading a source code and I found this:

```
extern size_t (*MEM_allocN_len)(const void *vmemh) ATTR_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;
```

and this:

```
extern void (*MEM_freeN)(void *vmemh);
```

I cannot figure out what is the function name and what is/are parameter/s.
How should I interpret these function declarations?

Comment: These are *variable* declarations, not function declarations. These variables have "pointer to function" type.

Comment: odd that cdecl hates these

Comment: MEM_allocN_len and MEM_freeN are pointer to functions. you can interpret is as this: `FUNTIONNAME` is replaced by `(*MEM_freeN)`

Comment: So in the first the first case the variable name is : ATTR_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT. The function name : MEM_allocN_len. The function parameter : *vmemh. And the function returned type: size_t. Am I right? If I am, what about the second? Doesn't it has a name?

Comment: @Kervens Volcy: No. Variable names are `MEM_allocN_len` and `MEM_freeN`. There are no "function names" of any kind here. `ATTR_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT` is a macro that contains some compiler-specific declaration attributes, which is completely inconsequential here. `vmemh` is a parameter name, but it is completely unnecessary here and can be discarded.

Comment: @Ant: Thanks! Since I have now an idea of what it is about i am going to search more on Google.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick helps!

Comment: cdecl will handle them, with some mods... it doesn't seem to understand size_t (change it to an int), leave off the macro name "ATTR_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT" and omit the variable name inside the function ("vmemh) ...for example:   "extern int (*MEM_allocN_len)(const void *)"   gets interpreted as "declare MEM_allocN_len as extern pointer to function (pointer to const void) returning int"